# understanding how return work for multiple iterations

Tags: javascript

I have been wrapping my head around recursion for a week now. And I want to say I have a good grasp on how it works. The detail I'm struggling with is what is being returned. In line 8 `return str;` does the function spit out str as an array ? For each iteration if so why can I not push it to a `newArr` ? Right now my output is `[undefined]` and I want to understand why this is.

```js
function permAlone(str, n, output = []) {

  var n = n || str.length

  if (n == 1) {
    // console.log(str)
    return str
  } else {
    for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
      permAlone(str, n - 1)
      if (n % 2) {
        var j = 1
      } else {
        j = i
      }
      swap(str, j - 1, n - 1)

    }
  }
}

function swap(a, i, j) {
  var temp = a[i]
  a[i] = a[j]
  a[j] = temp
}


var newArr = [];
newArr.push(permAlone('abc'.split('')));
console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: It works in the same way in all cases, it stops the execution of the current function and sends the return value to the caller, no matter where it is placed in a function.

Comment: I guess my question is does it output the str array? I don't understand why it's not being pushed to newArr.

Answer (score 1):

In most programming languages, the return statement is either "return" or "return value", where value is a variable or other information coming back from the subroutine. so return statement return the expected result you want. try the below examples with return and without return.
1)With return.

```
function sum(){
var test = 5 + 6;
return test;
}
console.log(sum());
```

2)Without return.

```
function sum(){
var test = 5 + 6;;
}
console.log(sum());
```

Comment: Sometimes you might get unexpected results, though.

Comment: You have to clear about the structure of you logic. Then you can resolve the issue of unexpected result.

Comment: And also you are not returning anything from your function that's why you are not  being pushed to newArr.

Comment: use following line at your function
return swap(str, j - 1, n - 1);